# modbus tcp connection process

Tags: stm32, modbus-tcp

I am trying to connect Mach3 software to STM32 microcontroler with MODBUS TCP

however I couldnot connect to Mach3 yet

at first Mach3 send a SYN message to STM32

then I respond to Mach3 MODBUS TCP SYN message with a ACK/SYN message

this time Mach3 must send an ACK

but Mach3 responds with RST message and gives connection timeout - see picture
[wireshark picture of ethernet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10rTm.jpg)

I suspect that I couldnot send the sequence number and acknowledgement number correctly in my SYN/ACK message

or what else mistake I do ?

do you know a modbus TCP library which I can get some help ?

thank you

Comment: Welcome to [so].Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: To make it easier for the rest of us, you can use the `ip.addr==192.168.1.110` filter in wireshark to remove the noise.

Comment: I think I cannot corectly calculate the sequence and acknowledge numbers in SYN/ACK message

thats why the RST message

do you know a formula for calculating these ?